# Ext JS code review check list

Tags: javascript, extjs

Can any one share a code review check list for Ext JS in common and specially for Ext JS 3.4 ?

Comment: Code Review is for actual code reviews, not questions about code reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a specific list for Ext JS, you will have to compile your own one. There are plenty of code review check lists to be found in the internet. Most likely you put together several lists depending on your needs:

- general list on correctness (e.g. requirements, tests passed)
- general list on coding (names, method length, e.g. see book "Code Complete")
- general lists on JavaScript fundamentals (JSLint result, bug patterns, e.g. see book "JavaScript the good parts")
- general lists on Object Orientation (SRP, sizes, APIs, coupling, e.g. see book "Clean Code")
- add more general lists, depending on your environment

and the most important the special lists, you come up after being bitten by something in the past. These are your specific rules

- coding standards
- adherence to naming standards
- adherence to architecture
- etc.

For the ExtJS specific part, you might also ask on the mailing list of ExtJS developers/users for common pitfalls and problems when using ExtJS. I'm sure the ExtJS community likes to have an Anti-Pattern list of things to avoid (and most likely this was your original question...).

Answer (score 3):

- Does it match the requirements?
- Is the code correct?
- Is the code high quality?
- Do the unit tests have 100% coverage
- Does the code adhere to the style guides